# Mat-autocomplete dropdown closes selecting with enter

Tags: angular, angular-material

Mat-autocomplete dropdown closes selecting with enter

im bulding a autocomplete chiplist. and i want to be able to select multiple options before i close the list. it works perfect when using a mouse, but when i select with enter the list closes.

does anybody have a solution for this problem?

Comment: replicate your issue in a stackblitz instance and share the link with us, please. It would make the process a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

You should set `[matChipInputSeparatorKeyCodes]` for your `matChipInput`, is the list of key codes that will trigger a chipEnd event. **`Defaults to [ENTER]`**.

###### html:

```
<input [matChipInputSeparatorKeyCodes]="separatorKeysCodes" ...>
```

###### ts:

```
import { COMMA } from '@angular/cdk/keycodes';

separatorKeysCodes = [COMMA]; // for example
```

Full Example: https://material.angular.io/components/chips/examples#chips-input

Api: https://material.angular.io/components/chips/api#MatChipInput